# How to send serial data with events?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, arduino-esp8266

I'm making two arduinos communicate via Serial. It works but there is a structure problem: When I send a data from one arduino, the other one has no idea what is she receiving ...

Is it possible to add a "title" to each communication; a way to communicate properly with events like you would do with sockets or HTTP.
Is there a library to achieve that ?

I've think to serialize and deserialize JSON to add a "title" in the data but it is overkill..

Answer (score 0):

You could use something akin to serial.parseint() to break up your serial transmissions and then look for a header.  If you seperate all comms by a comma then you'll know that the first parsed out will be the header.  The arduino example to parse commas is shown below:

```
void loop() {
  // if there's any serial available, read it:
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {

    // look for the next valid integer in the incoming serial stream:
    int red = Serial.parseInt();
    // do it again:
    int green = Serial.parseInt();
    // do it again:
    int blue = Serial.parseInt();

    // look for the newline. That's the end of your sentence:
    if (Serial.read() == '\n') {
      // constrain the values to 0 - 255 and invert
      // if you're using a common-cathode LED, just use "constrain(color, 0, 255);"
      red = 255 - constrain(red, 0, 255);
      green = 255 - constrain(green, 0, 255);
      blue = 255 - constrain(blue, 0, 255);

      // fade the red, green, and blue legs of the LED:
      analogWrite(redPin, red);
      analogWrite(greenPin, green);
      analogWrite(bluePin, blue);

      // print the three numbers in one string as hexadecimal:
      Serial.print(red, HEX);
      Serial.print(green, HEX);
      Serial.println(blue, HEX);
    }
  }
}
```

After you get the header you can do a switch() statement to check the case:
e.g.

```
while (Serial.available() > 0) {
     int header = Serial.parseInt();
     ...
     switch (header){
         case header1:
           code here...
           break;
         case header2:
           code here...
           break;
         default:
           break;
    }
```